# VBA activate chart created in different function

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have created a chart in one function as shown:

```
Sub CreateChart()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt as Chart

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

End Sub
```

How can I activate this chart in a different function where I want to move it to a certain cell? I am using the following code but it keeps giving me errors and won't activate the chart. I even gave the chart a Title and tried to use it's title t activate it but it won't recognize the name:

```
Sub MoveChart()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chrt").Activate
With ActiveChart.Parent
.Left = Range("N2").Left
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why activate it? You may use directly the chrt object that you stored, which you may pass to a parametrized `MoveChart` subroutine:

```
Sub MoveChart(ByVal chrt As Excel.Chart)

        With chrt.Parent
                .Left = Range("N2").Left
        End With

End Sub
```

with the difference that now you may move *any* chart you'd like.

**Later edit**

The second macro fails because the chart remains unnamed. Trying to access the chart by the name of the *VBA variable* doesn't do the trick. So, try this:

```
    Sub CreateChart()

            Dim chrt As Shape

            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
                    Set chrt = .AddChart()
                    Let chrt.Name = "New chart"
            End With

    End Sub

    Sub MoveChart()

            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .ChartObjects("New chart").Left = .Range("N2").Left
            End With

    End Sub
```

Don't forget to modify the code to use other chart names, other sheet names etc.

Comment: When I try this, I am unable to run the macro. It won't show up as a macro on the macro list.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're not trying to program complicated stuff... usually activating sheets and objects is not very efficient. But, okay, the mistake in the code you wrote is that the chart name is not set correctly. I'll come back with code written your way.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am fairly new to VBA, I've only been coding in it for about 3 weeks now so I have a lot to learn. But yes, no complicated stuff as of now haha.

Comment: I get an error stating "Out of memory" at the line `Let chrt.name = "New Chart"`

Comment: @art123456 Is `chrt` declared as `Shape` or as `Chart` in your `CreateChart`? Please compare with the code that I posted.

Comment: A shape. I have: `Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart` where sh is: `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TraceTable")' and they are dimensioned as chart and as worksheet

Comment: So, actually, you didn't use my code on `CreateChart`. :-) Okay, first of all you just said that your declaration is `Dim chrt As Chart` so `chrt` has the type `Chart` not `Shape`. Please add in your sub, after setting `chrt`, the following statement: `Let chrt.Parent.Name = "New chart"`, because charts don't have names, but their parents (which are shapes) do.

Comment: @art123456 Please see the comment above, I forgot to tag your ID.

Comment: That works wonders! Thank you so much for your help :) I do want to ask you something though if you'd be so kind to answer for me. I have seen this before and have tried to read about it, but it's hard to understand: `ByVal`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for some reason your code worked and now it doesn't anymore. I tried it that one time and I had to go and haven't worked on the program since my last comment. Anyways, now I am getting an error that states: `The item with the specified name wasn't found` on the line: `.ChartObjects("New Chart").Left = .Range("N2").Left`

Comment: @art123456 Well, the error tells you what's wrong. Long translation would be: in the active workbook, in the sheet named `"Sheet1"` there is no chart who's name is `"New Chart"`. Possible errors: 1) The chart was not created, or is created with a similar name (typos, extra spaces, case differences), 2) The chart was created in other worksheet/workbook actually, 3) the active workbook is not the one that you want (as I said before activating stuff to accessing stuff is weird, at least for me). So, here's your detective story: try to find out what actually went wrong. :-)

Comment: The thing is, I know that the chart is created onto the correct sheet. Because I set eh sheet as `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TraceTable")` and then I set the chart as `Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart` so now I know it's created onto that worksheet. The name of the chart using `Let chrt.Parent.Name = "EIT"` makes the chart name "EIT", and then I call the chart later in the `MoveChart` Sub using the name "EIT". This is bugging me because it definitely worked once and then I don't know what I did to change it! :/

Comment: @art123456  Are you used to work with the Immediate Window in the VBA Editor? Because that helps you get immediate answers about this.

Comment: @ CST-Link The immediate window? I'm not sure what that is so probably not.